# EC2 User data - Disable it after all conditions are met in user data

Tags: amazon-web-services, powershell, amazon-ec2

I'm trying to rename hostname and add to AD of a spot instance. It is a simple powershell script. I've read the docs that by default user data will be disable after it gets executed once and if `<persist>true</persist>` is used it will not be disabled.

I think I saw somewhere this(enabling to be run at each startup) is done via taskscheduler but can't find the link.

Can someone point me to the task scheduler job or the way to manually disable the userdata once my `if` conditions are met.

```
<powershell>
Set-ExecutionPolicy unrestricted -Force

$instanceName = "test-name5"

$username = "domain\username"
$password = "password" | ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force
$cred = New-Object -typename System.Management.Automation.PSCredential($username, $password)


Start-Sleep -s 5

$hostname = hostname
$domain = (Get-WmiObject win32_computersystem).Domain
if (!($hostname -eq $instanceName)){
     Rename-Computer -NewName $instanceName -restart -force
}Elseif (!($domain -eq 'my.domain.local')){
     Start-Sleep -s 5
     Add-Computer -DomainName my.domain.local -OUPath "OU=Windows,OU=QAServers,OU=Servers,DC=my,DC=domain,DC=local" -Credential $cred -Force -Restart -erroraction 'stop'
}Else {
     ####code to disable the running of userdata once above conditions 
     are met####
}
</powershell>
<persist>true</persist>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's worth reading the [ec2config-service](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/WindowsGuide/ec2config-service.html) documentation, as the setting you want is referenced in there.

You want the `Ec2HandleUserData` setting, which is configured in the `Config.xml`.

Powershell can easily update this setting:

```
$path = 'C:\Program Files\Amazon\Ec2ConfigService\Settings\config.xml'
$xml = [xml](Get-Content $path)
$state = $xml.Ec2ConfigurationSettings.Plugins.Plugin | where {$_.Name -eq 'Ec2HandleUserData'}
$state.State = 'Disabled'
$xml.Save($path)
```

I use this code when creating custom AMI's to re-enable userdata handling (`$state.State = 'Enabled'`).

---

EDIT: The above is for `ec2config` not `ec2launch` which is what the OP is using. I'd missed this originally.

I this case I think you need to change the way your script runs, rather than use `<persist>` and then try to disable its functionality, I would remove the persist tag and call `InitializeInstance.ps1 –Schedule` ([documentation link](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/WindowsGuide/ec2launch.html)) in your `if` for the conditions you want the userdata to re-run:

```
if ($hostname -ne $instanceName) {
    & C:\ProgramData\Amazon\EC2-Windows\Launch\Scripts\InitializeInstance.ps1 -Schedule
    Rename-Computer -NewName $instanceName -Restart -Force
}
elseif ($domain -ne 'my.domain.local') {
    & C:\ProgramData\Amazon\EC2-Windows\Launch\Scripts\InitializeInstance.ps1 -Schedule
    Add-Computer -DomainName aws.macmillan.local -OUPath "OU=Windows,OU=QAServers,OU=Servers,DC=my,DC=domain,DC=local" -Credential $cred -Force -Restart -ErrorAction 'stop'
}
```

Comment: Does it work for 2016 servers as well? Because Ec2config was dropped and Ec2Launch is used in its place now. I'll check the doc you provided as well. Thanks

Comment: No, that setting is for ec2config not ec2launch.

Comment: The code you provided didn't work for me. My code logic should be put inside the `InitializeInstance.ps1` for it to work. But looking at that powershell script gave some insight.
- I could place my code inside that script 
- or I can add code for creating/disabling a scheduled task
- or If I can find the aws scheduled task , I can disable it after running the number of times I require it o

Fortunately I found the aws scheduled task

Answer (score 1):

As I said in the comments of the previous answer, I had 3 options and since I found the aws scheduled task I went with the last option. Answering my own question since it'll be easy to spot the code.

```
<powershell>
Set-ExecutionPolicy unrestricted -Force

#Enter instance hostname here 
$instanceName = "test-name8"

$username = "domain\username"
#Using ssm parameter store to avoid having the password in plaintext
$password = (Get-SSMParameterValue -Name AD-Password -WithDecryption $True -Region us-east-1).Parameters[0].Value | ConvertTo-SecureString -asPlainText -Force
Start-Sleep -s 3
$cred = New-Object -typename System.Management.Automation.PSCredential($username, $password)


Start-Sleep -s 5

$hostname = hostname
$domain = (Get-WmiObject win32_computersystem).Domain
if ($hostname -ne $instanceName){
     Rename-Computer -NewName $instanceName -restart -force
}Elseif ($domain -ne 'my.domain.local'){
     Start-Sleep -s 5
     Add-Computer -DomainName my.domain.local -OUPath "OU=Windows,OU=QAServers,OU=Servers,DC=my,DC=domain,DC=local" -Credential $cred -Force -Restart -erroraction 'stop'
}Else {
     Disable-ScheduledTask -TaskName "Amazon Ec2 Launch - Userdata Execution"
     Unregister-ScheduledTask -TaskName "Amazon Ec2 Launch - Userdata Execution"
}
</powershell>
<persist>true</persist>
```

note: a role that has ssm policies must be attached while launching the server for this ssm parameter command to work.

Comment: This will restart the server two times and finally should disable the scheduled task but that doesn't happen for some reason. But when I manually restart the server after it gets added to AD , the userdata script runs again and goes to the Else block and scheduled task gets disabled(it doesn't get unregistered)

The functionality I expected is met , hence not trying to find out why the task is not getting disabled during the automatic restarts

Comment: You can rename the computer at the same time as you join it `Add-Computer -DomainName "$adDomainName" -Credential $mycreds -NewName "$hostName" -Restart -Verbose`

Answer (score 0):

I was solving similar issue and I had to change Windows Server 2016 hostname and enroll it to Elastic Server Fleet. Also I could not allow instance to be rebooted. I used this code to solve this.

**NB.** I understand that it is not direct way of doing this and has numerous drawbacks, but in my circumstances goal was achieved without negative impact.

```
<powershell>
$ComputerName = "MyPCRandomName"
Set-ItemProperty -path "HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Tcpip\Parameters" -name "Hostname" -value $ComputerName
elastic-agent enroll --enrollment-token 123 --url=321
</powershell>
```